# Is there any way of making evil mode work inside list-packages?

Tags: evil

I've installed the `evil` package to make emacs keybindings more like `vim`. After installing it I put the following lines on my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
```

It works fine when I'm editing files. However, if I try to use the command `:list-packages`, the vim keybindings are not working at all... The standard emacs commands work fine in this case, but I'd like to use vim keybindings in this case as well. Is there any way of configuring `evil` mode to use vim keybindings everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest [evil-collection](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection)
or you can set the initial state manually like [it](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection/blob/master/modes/package-menu/evil-collection-package-menu.el#L38):

```lisp
(evil-set-initial-state 'package-menu-mode 'motion)
```

Comment: I guess for `package-menu-mode`, if not using evil-collection or [evilified-state](https://github.com/mohsenil85/evil-evilified-state), as there is no editing to be done, using evil `motion` state would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @dalanicolai, it makes sense.